# plone add-on collective.sendaspdf: login required for downloading page

Tags: plone

I'm using collective.sendaspdf for pdf download of plone pages, but it asks users to login whene they download a public content.

This appears strange as it happens just in the production server, not in the development server (the only difference seems that the latter is started in foreground mode).

Of course I can't assign particular permissions on objects to anonymous users, so I guess the problem is somewhere else

thanks to Jean's suggestion, i enabled the verbose security and the error is "Unauthorized: You are not allowed to access '@@at_base_edit_view' in this context" 
This looks strange to me as the page is the view of my content-type archetype-based, and it is published so it is visible to anonymous users. I repeat also that I have the development server with the same software installed where the authorization is correctly given, i.e. the page can be downloaded by anyone without login...what changes is the network configuration (I have an apache that performs some url rewriting in front of my zope server, but this just affects the path of the plone site to be hidden) 
I wonder if I can manage to correct this just through the sendaspdf configuration. I don't know which additional info I could provide about the environment/configuration. I'm running Plone 4.0.4 + collective.sendaspdf 2.0

Comment: I think this is a perfectly reasonable question. The answer is to enable verbose security, e.g. by running the zope process in the foreground and watching the console messages. I couldn't find really good current docs that explain the best way to approach this, but scan http://collective-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/buildout/deployment.html?highlight=verbose http://collective-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/testing_and_debugging/logging.html?highlight=verbose http://plone.org/documentation/kb/debug-unauthorized/ https://weblion.psu.edu/trac/weblion/wiki/VerboseSecurity

Comment: thanks Jean, i enabled the verbose security and the error is "Unauthorized: You are not allowed to access '@@at_base_edit_view' in this context"

Comment: Does the traceback give you any info on the line where it fails ? It is possible that sendaspdf tries to access something it should not (I did my best to avoid getting errors on this case but apparently I'm missing some case :/ ) when trying to render the page that the user is seeing. Did you also install jquery.pyproxy ? the Ajax version works better normally (we just get the source code with Javascript and it uses the exact code that the user sees, including parts changed with JS for example)

Comment: @mede: you need to provide the full traceback information..

Comment: I implemented a workaround: the problem is that sendaspdf in the method get_page_source, when is unable to extract from the url the view_name (I don't know if this depends from a bad configuration I did), it checks the 'immediate_view' value. In the case of archetype based content, this is actc_edit, that requires permissions, so I changed that line of code from "view_name = context_type.getProperty('immediate_view')" to "view_name = context_type.getProperty('default_view')" and now it works. Thanks again for the tip on the authorization exception debug

Comment: Well, that's a bug in sendaspdf. I'll try to include a fix in the next release, thanks for pointing it out :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the problem was due to a bug in how collective.sendaspdf handles archetype-based content types, it's possible to workaround it by replacing the code:

```
view_name = context_type.getProperty('immediate_view')
```

with

```
view_name = context_type.getProperty('default_view')
```

in the method `get_page_source` of `base.py`, or by waiting the next release of the product.